# Is it possible to enter a background image size with variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image, background-size

```js
var setSize = $('#inputSize').val();

$("#canvas").css({
  'background-size': '100px' + setSize
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputSize" class="form-control" type="number" value="">
```

Comment: try it with jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but there is something off in your code.

better do it this way

```
var setSize = parseFloat($('#inputSize').val());
var size = isNaN(setSize) ? 0 : setSize;
$("#canvas").css({
  'background-size': 100 + size + 'px'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want to add CSS on entering value in the text box.

HTML

```
<input id="inputSize">
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#inputSize').on('input', function() {
  var setSize = 100 + parseInt($('#inputSize').val()) + 'px';

  $("#canvas").css({
    'background-size' : setSize
  });
});
```